# P4 diff doesn't work on Redhat linux 5.7

Tags: editor, perforce

o-xterm-91:maxwell1/arch/simt/func/proto-compiler> p4 diff run_passes.pl

==== //arch/simt/func/proto-compiler/run_passes.pl#247 - /home/scratch.ankurj_maxwell-info/maxwell1/arch/simt/func/proto-compiler/run_passes.pl ====
mgdiff: error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

All other perforce commands are working except for the diff.
Suggest alternative's or fixes.

I am using Centos, Redhat linux 5.7 enterprise version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have configured a custom diff program using the P4DIFF configuration setting: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/env.P4DIFF.html

Try clearing the P4DIFF and DIFF configuration settings, and you can use the built-in Perforce command-line diff, which is a simple textual diff program.

Else, try reviewing the "mgdiff" installation materials at the mgdiff site ant see if you can re-install or repair the Motif libraries on your machine. http://packages.debian.org/sid/text/mgdiff